# Failing to build nvidia kmod : mockbuild does not exist

Tags: rpm, nvidia, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build nvidia drivers on fedora 23 (installed on a qubes virtual machine if that matters) and as you'll be able to see in a second I'm confronted with a major problem that prevents me from building it. See by yourself :

```
[user] $ rpmbuild --nodeps -D "kernels 3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64" --rebuild nvidia-kmod-358.16-1.fc23.src.rpm 
Installing nvidia-kmod-358.16-1.fc23.src.rpm
warning: nvidia-kmod-358.16-1.fc23.src.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5ca6c469: NOKEY
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.8Fkbub
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/user/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ echo 'kmodtool error: Don'\''t know how to handle 3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64 -- /usr/lib/modules/3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64/build/Makefile not found'
kmodtool error: Don't know how to handle 3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64 -- /usr/lib/modules/3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64/build/Makefile not found
+ exit 2
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.8Fkbub (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    nvidia-kmod-358.16-1.fc23.src.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5ca6c469: NOKEY
    user mockbuild does not exist - using root
    group mockbuild does not exist - using root
    user mockbuild does not exist - using root
    group mockbuild does not exist - using root
    user mockbuild does not exist - using root
    group mockbuild does not exist - using root
    user mockbuild does not exist - using root
    group mockbuild does not exist - using root
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.8Fkbub (%prep)
```

I'm following the instructions but it still fails which is quit daunting for a little user like me, does anyone know if there is a way for me to fix this mess ?

Comment: Why are you using kernel from F20 when you are on F23?

Comment: @msuchy cause i'm building for qubes